# Websocket connection failed after openend

Tags: npm, websocket, laravel-8, node-modules

I have created chat app between two. I'm using laravel with vue.js and using websocket for that.

**Node version : 14.21.3**

**npm version : 6.14.18**

**Laravel Framework : 8.83.27**

When I'm going to opened websocket with command `pm2 start public/js/socket-io-server.js`, server started successfully.

But I'm getting error like in console and couldn't send message (for chat - code for sending message is working),

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://chatapp.project.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed:                                  app.js?v=1.2:23734
```

So, is there anything else I need to check or install or something? Thanks.

Comment: Post code to assist you in this.

Answer (score 0):

We need the code for a better answer, but it could be a CORS issue. Is one of your clients running in a browser, or are they both running Node.JS? If Node.JS, then I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but if one of the clients is running in the browser, then make sure to set the Node.JS endpoint to provide [appropriate CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's pretty hard to help you.  But here's some general WS things to check.

- Does your initial handshake succeed?
- Are you receiving a close frame?  If so, it should tell you why the connection was closed.
- Are you starting and maintaining a heartbeat (ping/pong) to keep the connection alive?